# layout_below/layout_above doesnt work if relative layout has a background resource

Tags: android, android-layout

First scenario...Relative Layout has no background drawable resource set...the following code working totally as expected, screenshot is attached[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <Button android:text="Jill"
    android:id="@+id/btnJill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnJack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jack"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnJill"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second scenario...Relative Layout has a background drawable resource set...and now the result is messed up by just adding one line, screenshot is attached![image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:background="@drawable/background">
    <Button android:text="Jill"
    android:id="@+id/btnJill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnJack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jack"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnJill"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This has to be a bug..if not anyone has a solution.

Comment: android:background="@+id/background" ???? it must be something like
android:background="@drawable/background"

Comment: first of all thanx for the edit and sorry it was typo..i have edited the question again..do u hav a solution?

Comment: ok. let me try it out.

Comment: i tried your xml code and its working fine.

Comment: wonder why its not working fine in my case?? so u saying that you are getting same output for both the scenarios...the buttons are aligned below each other??

Comment: Yes. the button won't move after adding a background. they are aligned properly as expected.

Comment: Have you tried this on a device? Maybe it's a bug in the layout editor.

Comment: i tried it on the device same results..i have cleaned/ rebuild..still the same results

Comment: No..its definitely not a delay...and i did encounter this very same problem earlier when i was working on a complex layout..but that time i didnt want to waste time so i opted for other way...but it did occur on different machines too

Comment: do you have different layout files? Appears to be working on some and not on others.

Comment: no..just one..does anyone else here got successful in reproducing this problem??

Comment: its an image problem..changing the background image resolved it...but still need to figure out why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_below="@id/btnJill"` to `android:layout_below="@+id/btnJill"`